# VHD from WIM won't boot

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, wim

I have a wim obtained from a machine running Win10. I intend to spin this up as a VM in Hyper-V. This is the procedure so far:

1. create 40G VHD using Hyper-V manager.
2. mount the VHD using Computer Manager/Disk Management. 
   initialize the drive. 
   create a simple volume, format it, and assign it a drive letter.
3. using a command console with administrative privileges, run DISM applyimage

   dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:{file.wim} /Name:{image name} /ApplyDir:{drive} /CheckIntegrity
4. using the same command console, add the boot sector to the VHD

   bootsect /nt60 {drive}
5. Detach the VHD disk volume using Computer Manager/Disk Management

All of the above {drive} parameters are defined by the drive letter specified when the VHD was mounted as a simple volume in step 2.

After this, I create a VM in Hyper-V Manager, start it and it does not boot. Not sure what I need to crest this hurdle. Any suggestions are welcome. My overall goal is to use the VHD in Azure - I am just testing it locally.

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting context with this issue. Picking up from where I left off above:

6. Obtain an ISO image of Windows 10. I used build 1703.
7. Create a VM in Hyper-V Manager, using the VHD created in steps 1 to 5.
8. Double click on the new VM to connect to it.
9. Open the menu item File/Settings
10. Set the DVD Drive to use the image file from step 6.
11. Hit OK, closing the Settings.
12. Click the green Power on/Start command button - it will boot from the image

Once the win 10 Image loads:

13. Check the keyboard and language prefs and click "Install"
14. Click "Repair Your Computer"
15. Click "Troubleshoot"
16. Click "Command Prompt"

Once the command prompt is shown:

17. Type the following (this will set disk 0 part 1 active and apply a boot record):

diskpart
DISKPART> list disk
DISKPART> select disk 0
DISKPART> list partition
DISKPART> select partition 1
DISKPART> active
DISKPART> list volume
DISKPART> exit
C:
bcdboot c:\windows /l en-us

18. Exit the repair disk, turn off the VM, and power it back up. Wallah!

Comment: My intent is to use this for a VM in Azure, so the remainder of the procedure is here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json